# Update Statement with subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update, subquery

### MS Access Update Statement with subquery

I have Order table and OrderDetails table. OrderDetails table has orderline items with quantity and subtotal. I would like to run a query to update "Total Amount Before Discount" in Order table with the sum value of correspondent orderline subtotals.

The query I have now is below. I couldn't run it in Access. It tells me "you have written a subquery that can return more than one field without using the EXISTS reserved word in the main queries FROM clause. revise the SELECT statement of the subquery to request only one field."

```
UPDATE [Order] INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Order.ID = OrderDetails.[Order ID]
SET [Order].[Total Amount Before Discount] = 
    (SELECT Order.ID, Sum(OrderDetails.[Subtotal After Discount]) AS [SumOfSubtotal After Discount]
     FROM [Order] INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Order.ID = OrderDetails.[Order ID]
     GROUP BY Order.ID)
     WHERE (((Order.ID)=[OrderDetails].[Order ID]));
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need the join.  How about the following:

```
UPDATE [Order] 
SET [Order].[Total Amount Before Discount] = 
    (
      SELECT Sum(OrderDetails.[Subtotal After Discount])
      FROM OrderDetails 
      WHERE [Order].ID = OrderDetails.[Order ID]
    )
```

The above query will update **Total Amount Before Discount** for every record in the **Order** table.  If you want to update just a certain **Order Id** then use the following:

```
UPDATE [Order] 
SET [Order].[Total Amount Before Discount] = 
    (
      SELECT Sum(OrderDetails.[Subtotal After Discount])
      FROM OrderDetails 
      WHERE [Order].ID = OrderDetails.[Order ID]
    )
WHERE [Order].ID = 786
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [DSum Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dsum-function-HA001228829.aspx) in your `UPDATE` query.

```sql
UPDATE [Order] AS o
SET o.[Total Amount Before Discount] = 
    DSum
        (
            "[Subtotal After Discount]",
            "OrderDetails",
            "[Order ID]=" & o.ID
        );
```

Note if the data type of `[Order ID]` is text instead of numeric, add quotes around the value you supply in the `DSum` expression ...

```
            "[Order ID]='" & o.ID & "'"
```

Comment: **@HansUp**, I am curious do you know if the **DSum** function is any faster than using a sub query?

Comment: In this case, I doubt it.  You may hear oft-repeated claims that `DSum` is *slower*.  That shouldn't be the case here either. With an index on `OrderDetails.[Order ID]`, either way should be reasonably fast.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of observations, UPDATE has to be re-written:
Re-writing your query, we get - if you are updating only one record, you don't care about the GROUP BY:

```
UPDATE [Order]
SET [Order].[Total Amount Before Discount] = 
(Sum(OrderDetails.[Subtotal After Discount])
FROM [Order] INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Order.ID = OrderDetails.[Order ID]
WHERE (([Order].ID)=[OrderDetails].[Order ID]);
```

First thing, you cannot UPDATE a JOIN/INNER JOIN..

Second, you cannot update more than one column the way you wrote the statement, it has to be something like:

```
UPDATE [order]
SET    col1 = somevalue,
       col2 = anothervalue
WHERE  (([order].id) = [orderdetails].[Order ID]);
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: -1 You state that `if you are updating only one record, you don't care about the GROUP BY`.  Then the SQL below it does not limit the query to ***one*** record.  Not to mention, the statement is invalid.  You are missing a `)` and ***Order*** is a reserved word and needs to be in brackets.

Comment: ORDER is reserved word.  However, Access and SQL will allow when you use square braces [ORDER] is valid for the table name in Access.

Comment: You are right however you are missing the brackets around a couple of occurrences