# SQL Query to Update Table1 From Table 2 Row Count With Where Criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, sql-update

I have two tables :
First table
tbl_SUMMARY : ID_CUSTOMER (PK), ADDRESS, TEL, PRINCIPAL, INTEREST
the first table have primary_key, i have to update the principal and interest field by counting the row number in the second table)

second table
tbl_DUMP : ID_CUSTOMER, DATE, AMOUNT, CODES
the second table has no primary key with hundreds of row, the codes field is where the principal or interest (for the where clause), i have to count this table

I have tried the following :

```
UPDATE tbl_SUMMARY
SET tbl_SUMMARY.PRINCIPAL=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_DUMP
WHERE tbl_DUMP.ID_CUSTOMER=tbl_SUMMARY.ID_CUSTOMER AND tbl_DUMP.CODES='PRINCIPAL'
```

this query gives me error Operation Must Use an Updateable Query

Any help appreciated

i have tried the above query but it's not working

expecting to update the first table by counting rows in the second table

Comment: Do you want to count all rows in the second table or only those satisfying the where clause?

Comment: only those in the where clause because its a dump table, the codes field consist of principal and interest

Comment: that doesn't look like a Mysql error message. Please include the complete error message

Comment: I'm using Tado to connect to mdb, and use Tquery in delphi

Comment: mdb are Ms Access

Comment: yes i just need the query for the above

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update Statement with subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238824/update-statement-with-subquery)

Comment: i think its sum query what I need is count query for the above, I have done sum and have no problem the query run as expected, but for count query still not working

Comment: perhaps its because mdb access table2 tbl_dump has no primary key? but the dump table just a row of data with duplicates of ids that I need to count the rows

Comment: The error message is clear. Access does not allow UPDATE with a non-updatable (non-editable) query. Aggregate query is non-updatable. Common topic. Could use DCount() domain aggregate function or VBA loop a recordset.

Comment: How to use dcount on two tables?